# Animating an img sequence : sprite vs src replace, what is the fastest?

Tags: image, src, css-sprites, onscroll

I have a png sequence exported from a video that I need to playback on scroll.

I see 2 possibilities here :

1. Create a single sprite img and animate it's position on scroll
2. Replace the src of a img tag on scroll

The first option comes to me as being the better one with short sequences, but mine is quite long (more than 50 frames).

Or maybe there is another option that is more efficient that I didn't think of ?

I'd like to hear your thoughts on this one ! Thanks !

Comment: Hey @Simon, could you elaborate a little more on the desired behaviour? Is your intention that you scroll the page and a background image changes? And do you want there to be any transitional animation between the image changes?

Comment: Hi @jh3y, thanks for the reply ! The sequence will be displayed in a fixed div on the page. When the user scrolls, the animation should play as if it was a video. The only difference is that the scrolls controls the playback. I don't need any special transition between images, but if it can help make it look better, why not !

Comment: I'd imagine the quickest/performant way to render new changes would be via the `background-position` of a sprite. Then on the JavaScript side, it's just a matter of defining a framerate within your scroll handler.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but I have lots of images so the sprite will be huge. Guess I'll have to test the two options to see the difference ! Thanks !